# sql didn't get me all the rows

Tags: sql

I have a query that is gathering information based on a set of conditions. And when  I run the query it didn't get me all the data I should get more than 3000000 but I get only 600000 and I don't know why? Need help

```
SELECT      dbo.mediainteraction.ani
            ,dbo.mediainteraction.createtime
            ,dbo.classificationcode.description
            ,dbo.employee.fullname
            ,dbo.employee.loginname
            ,dbo.mediainteraction.pkey
FROM        dbo.agentsegment
RIGHT JOIN  dbo.taskperformedcode
RIGHT JOIN  dbo.mediainteraction    ON dbo.taskperformedcode.pkey = dbo.mediainteraction.pkey
RIGHT JOIN  dbo.classificationcode  ON dbo.taskperformedcode.code_key = dbo.classificationcode.pkey 
                                    ON dbo.agentsegment.pkey = dbo.mediainteraction.pkey 
RIGHT JOIN  dbo.employee            ON dbo.agentsegment.employee_key = dbo.employee.pkey 
WHERE       (dbo.mediainteraction.createtime >= '2016-7-24')
AND         (dbo.mediainteraction.createtime < '2016-7-25')
```

Comment: How can we possibly know?  We can't debug this against your database for you.  Start with a simplified query and add logic one clause at a time.  Determine where specifically the results are different from what you'd expect.

Comment: Why are you writing your `ON` statements like that?  I realise cascading the `ON` statements is valid to the compiler, but it makes it extremely difficult to figure out what it's doing...

Comment: dear david ,, i actually did what you said but always i get same problem i didn't gt all the rows,,  and when i join 2 tables and select data from them i only get 25% from the data and the rest null this is my problem

Comment: dear siyual,, i am first make it using only where condition to join and its do ok but when i tried to add another table by design and  its change all the code using the join instead my code

Comment: Also when I remove the where it should get me all the data but when I do I get 25% from the data this is my problem its happen when I do simple join ,, I think the problems becouse the conication of the primary key I will check ,, thanks to you

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out you need to step through commenting out parts of your logic till you find your issue.

However the problem is likely due to using mediaineration.createtime in your WHERE statement as it is involved in a RIGHT JOIN due to that it makes all of your joins inner joins

Comment: Dear i first used inner Join but when I use it i get null for all data ,, and when I use another table's in deferint data base the join work normally when I use the same method , I will try to step the through commenting